# Flask - Delete zipfile after download

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to delete .zip file from server directory right after client has downloaded it, but everytime I'm trying to execute 'os.remove' there's an error: "file is used by another process etc etc etc"

This code is inside 'app.route' method

```
    if (buttonName == "downloadFactures"):
      with ZipFile('sampleDir.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
        for facturesData in notApprovedFactures:
          zipObj.write(facturesData[2])

        return send_from_directory(app.root_path, "sampleDir.zip", as_attachment=True)


    else:
     -- nothing important
```

I tried to do something like:

```
zipObj = ZipFile(blabla)
forLoop
  zipObj.write

zipObj.close()
zipDownload = send_from_directory
os.remove(here's path for zipFile in server directory)
return zipDownload
```

but it didn't work, obviously it didn't work because file is still being used by client which is downloading this zip.

So here's my question if anyone know, how can I remove that created zipFile from my server directory after client download it?

Comment: in the first code, make sure that `return send_from_directory` is _outside_ the with block so zipfile can be closed.

Comment: I was testing several ways to do that, and nothing, because the minimum zipfile size is ~50mb that's why I can't remove that file, because it is still being used by client, he is downloading that file... I don't know exactly when his browser has finished downloading

Comment: you could use `io.Bytes()` to create zip file in memory without writing on disk.